# The shortest path for pressing input text by keypad

Tags: c#, algorithm

I get custom string from user. Now I need to design the shortest route for pressing this string in keypad that includes 9 buttons.

Note:

- The solution letters should be arranged in alphabetically i.e. a, b, c, d, e, ...
- Each number should at least include a one keyboard characters

Solution if input text = 'hello'

1. a, b, c, d
2. e, f, g
3. h, i, j, k
4. l, m, n
5. o, p, q
6. r, s, t
7. u, v, w
8. x, y
9. z

Or

1. a, b, c, d
2. e, f, g
3. h, i, j, k
4. l, m, n
5. o
6. p
7. q
8. r
9. s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z

with this keypad i need press 3,2,4,4,5 for type 'hello'

So if you want to type 'hello' with this designed keypad, you only need to press the 5 keypad buttons as that is the fewest number of keys.

i think this question is solving with greedy approach or backtracking algorithms.

Comment: @rene no and it's not important

Comment: Interesting problem, but I think the question is too general to ever be useful to others.

Comment: @Yuck I disagree: although the specific answer to this specific question would probably be of no use to others, an answer offering a good approach to the problem could be of great value.

Answer (score 3):

Let's generalize the alphabet to {1, …, n}. Let k be the number of keys. For 1 ≤ i < j ≤ k, the cost (= number of presses) of a possible key {i, …, j} is 1f<sub>i</sub> + 2f<sub>i+1</sub> + … + (j - i + 1) f<sub>j</sub>, where f<sub>i</sub> is the frequency of letter i. We're looking for the minimum-cost exact cover consisting of exactly k keys.

This problem has the following *optimal substructure*: fix an arbitrary optimal solution and remove the key with {m + 1, …, n} on it. The result is an optimal solution for the problem with k - 1 keys and alphabet {1, …, m}; otherwise, we could improve the first optimal solution by rearranging the first k - 1 keys.

Accordingly, we can apply dynamic programming. For every 0 ≤ i ≤ n and every 0 ≤ j ≤ k, compute the optimal arrangement for {1, …, i} with j keys. The cost of this arrangement C<sub>i,j</sub> satisfies the recurrence

C<sub>0,j</sub> = 0 for all j ≥ 0
C<sub>i,0</sub> = ∞ for all i > 0
C<sub>i,j</sub> = min<sub>0 ≤ i' < i</sub> (C<sub>i',j-1</sub> + c<sub>i',j</sub>),

where c<sub>a,b</sub> is the cost of key {a, …, b}. One can recover the arrangement itself from the sequence of optimal arguments i'.

Comment: But in the case input stream contains more than `k` different chars your optimal substructure doesn't work. e.g K = 4, and input string is "string", how you will handle this, IMO what you said is first thing comes in mind, but it's not optimal. In fact this is a greedy solution not DP.

Answer (score 2):

Each valid keypad corresponds to a 26-bit number with exactly nine bits set to 1. With only 2042975 valid combinations to try, brute force should be the first thing to attempt, before other approaches that require more thinking. The algorithm would go like this pseudocode:

```
int best_score = int.max
list<int> keypads
for int mask between 1 and 1<<26
    if bit_count(mask) != 9 or mask ends in 1 continue
    int lookup[26]
    int p = 1
    for int i between 0 and 26
        lookup[i] = p
        if mask's bit i is set to 1, p = 1 ; otherwise, p = p + 1
    int total = 0
    for each char ch in word
        total = total + lookup[ch]
    if total < best
        keypads = new list {mask}
        best = total
    else if total == best
        keypads.add(mask)
print best, keypads
```